# Submitting multiple values to mysql database using one html option

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm having trouble with this part of my form. I'm not quite sure what's going wrong, so I thought I'd see if anyone here could throw me a hint.

My code is attempting to determine the sex of the user as well as their sexual orientation using only one option. I'm pretty sure this is possible, but I think my syntax is slightly off.

```
<select name="gender" title="gender" class="dropdown nextPanel <?=( $this->get('error_gender') === true ) ? 'error' : ''?>">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->localization->get( 'form1.choose' ); ?></option><!-- Text: - - Choose - - -->
    <option value="M" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'M' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Woman</option>
    <option value="F" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'F' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="M" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'M' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="F" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'F' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Woman</option>
</select>
```

I've been crawling documentation but I think I'm overlooking something really small and stupid. I know this one will come easy to someone out there! Thanks for any tips!

Comment: For clarification, when this submits it creates an error, and last I checked, it's outputting nothing at all.

Comment: Sex and Sexuality aren't binary. Sexuality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinsey_scale and Gender: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_gender Number of people isn't always 2, either. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory

Comment: Unfortunately the services of the website aren't suited for everybody : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="gender" title="gender" class="dropdown nextPanel <?=( $this->get('error_gender') === true ) ? 'error' : ''?>">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->localization->get( 'form1.choose' ); ?></option><!-- Text: - - Choose - - -->
    <option value="MF" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'M' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Woman</option>
    <option value="FM" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'F' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="MM" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'M' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="FF" <?=( $_POST['gender']['orientation'] == 'F' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Woman</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track; I realized I could submit ONE value and then operate on it after submission. I decided to simply go with values 1, 2, 3 and 4. Using a switch, php determines that if 1 is chosen, sex = M and seeking = F. I have no idea what the hell I was trying to do before, haha! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'orientation' index is not needed while retrieving values from $_POST. Try this:

```
<select name="gender" title="gender" class="dropdown nextPanel <?=( $this->get('error_gender') === true ) ? 'error' : ''?>">     
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->localization->get( 'form1.choose' ); ?></option><!-- Text: - - Choose - - -->     
    <option value="M" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'M' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Woman</option>     
    <option value="F" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'F' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Man</option>     
    <option value="M" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'M' . 'M')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Man</option>     
    <option value="F" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'F' . 'F')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Woman</option> 
</select>
```

I assume this page is posted back to self.

Answer (score 0):

When this field is POSTED, it will will show up as:

```
$_POST['gender'] = 'M'
```

-or-

```
$_POST['gender'] = 'F'
```

You cannot tell, from that limited information, what their preference is.

Also, the term `$_POST['gender']['orientation']` does not map to a valid array element, because the name of your input field is `"gender"`, not `"gender[orientation]"`.

What you should do is give the `<option>` tags the following values:

```
<option value="MF">
<option value="FM">
<option value="MM">
<option value="FF">
```

Then when you recieve it on the server, you can use array notation:

```
if($_POST['gender'][0] == 'M')
   // gender is male

if($_POST['gender'][1] == 'F')
   // seeking is female
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<select name="gender" title="gender" class="dropdown nextPanel <?=( $this->get('error_gender') === true ) ? 'error' : ''?>">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->localization->get( 'form1.choose' ); ?></option><!-- Text: - - Choose - - -->
    <option value="MF" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'MF')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Woman</option>
    <option value="FM" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'FM')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="MM" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'MM')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Man Seeking a Man</option>
    <option value="FF" <?=( $_POST['gender'] == 'FF')? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Woman Seeking a Woman</option>
</select>
```